# Ionic 3: Images disappear after running 'ionic cordova build android' command

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have tried numerous ways to solve this issue but I am not able to get to a permanent solution.

I have multiple pages which use images.
When I run `ionic serve -l` all the pages shows all the available images but when I run `ionic cordova build android` build command then the images start disappearing.

I tried changing the directories of my images. For example: `src/assets/img` or `www/images`.

So far I've tried all this approaches:

```
<img alt="logo" class="hybrid-image-center" src="assets/img/logo_altosa_xl.png" height="75px" margin-bottom="30px">
<img alt="logo" class="hybrid-image-center" src="./assets/img/logo_altosa_xl.png" height="75px" margin-bottom="30px">
<img alt="logo" class="hybrid-image-center" src="/assets/img/logo_altosa_xl.png" height="75px" margin-bottom="30px">
<img alt="logo" class="hybrid-image-center" src="/www/images/logo_altosa_xl.png" height="75px" margin-bottom="30px">
```

I tried changing the source of images but with all of these approaches, the images disappear after running the build command. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```
<img src="assets/imgs/cool-image.png">
```

Using background-image:

```
background-image: url('../assets/imgs/cool-image.png')
```